# Integrate $\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^2\right)dx$ using known sum

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Integrate

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^2\right)dx$$

using known sum

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$$

We can express the logarithm using Taylor series as
$$\ln\left(\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^2\right)=4\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$$

thus getting the integral of
$$4\int_0^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2k}}{2k+1}dx$$

$$4\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\left[x^{2k+1}\right]^\infty_0}{(2k+1)^2}dx$$

$$4\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)^2}dx$$

How should I proceed now? I can almost see the known sum in this, but not quite. I thought about separating this into two parts out of which one would be the known sum, but then I don't know what to do with the other one. Any ideas?

Comment: Suggestion: separate the integral into $0\ldots 1$ and $1\ldots\infty$ pieces, and apply the substitution $x\mapsto \frac1t$ for the latter piece.

Comment: Note the radius of convergence for your Taylor series is $1$, so obviously you cannot use it for the entire integral (at least not without an adjustment as Steven Stadnicki hints at above).

Comment: Obviously that Taylor series diverges for $x\ge1$. So your whole approach is doomed to failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people pointed out in the comment section, the radius of convergence for this power series is $1$ so you should split the integral from $0$ to $1$ and $1$ to $\infty.$

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^2\right)dx=\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^2\right)dx+\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^2\right)dx \\
=\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}4\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)}dx+\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^2\right)dx \\
=4\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}+\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^2\right)dx=\frac{\pi^2}{2}+\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^2\right)dx$$

For the right side let $x=\frac{1}{t}$ then

$$\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^2\right)dx=\int_0^1\frac{1}{t}\ln\left(\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)^2\right)dt=4\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{2}.$$

So you get
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^2\right)dx=\frac{\pi^2}{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{2}=\pi^2.$$